# PHP DOMNode's getLineNo method won't return line number larger than 65535

Tags: php, dom

DOMNode's getLineNo method is to get line number for where the node is defined. But if the file has more than 65535 lines then the method will not return those high line numbers. Is there any work-around for it?

Comment: This might be a compilation option. Have you tried to build the extension from sources?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get line number for a node won't return line number larger than 65535.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402034/get-line-number-for-a-node-wont-return-line-number-larger-than-65535)

Answer (score -1):

Possible work around found at php.net:

```
<?php
$text = $node->ownerDocument->saveXML($node);
$line += substr_count($text, "\n");
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.getlineno.php