# Get line number for a node won't return line number larger than 65535.

Tags: php, dom

DOMNode's getLineNo() method is to get line number for where the node is defined.

But if the file has more than 65535 lines then the method, it will not return those high line numbers. Is there any work-around for it?

Please suggest any alternative. 
any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I understand that your XML file is very big.

If you use libxml 2.9 or higher this is no longer a problem but you have to define a specific option.

```
<?php
define('XML_PARSE_BIG_LINES', 4194304);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml, XML_PARSE_BIG_LINES);
?>
```