# R XML package - getLineNumber - line number above 65535 - limit inherited from libxml2

Tags: r, xml, runtime, libxml2, line-numbers

We are using the function getLineNumber from the R XML package. Some of our XML data files are quite large, and we inherit a bug from libxml2 limiting the returned line number to 65535 (stored in an unsigned int).

The problem is old and well-known by the library maintainers:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/-/issues/361

Im PHP, they overcome the problem at runtime:

[Get line number for a node won't return line number larger than 65535.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402034/get-line-number-for-a-node-wont-return-line-number-larger-than-65535)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php

Would it be feasible to do something similar in R?

Comment: have you tried https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xml2/index.html? And your question is off-topic for SO.